Furnace blows cold air, shuts off, then blows warm air
When changing the temperature on my thermostat, the blower kicks on and only blows cold air. This drops the temperature about 2-4°.
After running for a few minutes, the blower shuts off. About 30 seconds later, it kicks back on and blows hot air.
I thought it was the old thermostat, so I replaced it with a Wyze thermostat. No change.
The furnace is a little older. It’s a Lennox Conservator G11E.
Any ideas would be lovely.

Does the furnace follow the same pattern (cold air for a few minutes, shut off, then blow hot air) at other times, ie when the thermostat calls for heat without the set point being changed?

Any time the furnace kicks on. Whether I change the temperature or not. It’ll kick on, blow cold, shut off, kick on again, blow warm. I just bought the house, so I only have a few days of data.

Do not think it is the thermostat, they are usually only on/off furnace control.  Temp sensors/control board on the furnace are more likely.  Most are burner heats up and then the blower/fan kicks in.  On shut off burner turns off then the fan blows till cool down.  Testing first before replacing parts is usually cheaper.

Any blink or LED display codes on the furnace control panel? It's almost certainly failing to fire, then succeeding when it retries. I can tell you from personal experience that eventually it's going to finish failing.

No, the furnace had no visible lights or any place that even has a spot for them, from what I can see.

Based on a brief search I see your model of furnace is gas-fueled, has a two-stage ignition (a spark ignites a pilot, which in turn ignites the main gas), and has relatively primitive controls built into the gas valve assembly.
It sounds like what's happening is that the gas is not igniting reliably, or is not being sensed reliably, and so the control retries.
You can try watching the furnace to better understand where in its sequence things go awry. I'm not familiar with this specific model of integrated gas valve and ignition controller but I'd expect its operation to be as follows:

Valve turns on pilot gas
Spark ignition starts (you'll hear a snapping sound and see a small blue arc)
Pilot gas ignites
Valve turns main gas on
Main gas ignites

Somewhere in there the valve/control detects that the pilot flame ignited - probably between steps 3 and 4. This is called "flame proving." The electrode from which the spark jumps is likely also the sensor used for this.
If you observe the pilot and/or main gas igniting but then being shut off immediately that's an indicator that the flame proving is failing. You could try cleaning the electrode with fine sandpaper, emery cloth, or even a scouring pad like Scotch-brite.
Beyond that.. you might need to get a pro on site.

That is excellent information. I will watch it next time I’m there and see what I can find.
